# Are there any examples in the .Net framework that use spinlock or spinwait?

Tags: .net, multithreading, spinlock, spinwait

I had a look at the concurrent collections but they appear to use normal locking underneath the hood. Are there any good examples in the .Net framework that use this locking construct?

---

I initially looked at ConcurrentDictionary. I saw it was using normal locks but the BlockingCollection class uses SpinWait in its internal methods.

Comment: Why would you do that? spin lock is a busy waiting mechanism, i.e. using resources without doing anything useful

Comment: Purely educational. I don't think I would ever need to do this. But I just want to learn more about it and have a look at a decent example. Most examples are quite contrived at best.

Comment: That you can't seem to find real life examples already says a lot in my opinion.

Comment: @Daniel: true :). But they included it for a reason. I just want to know more about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by *normal locking* ? Some kind of `lock(object) { ... }` construct ?

If yes, you should look at `ConcurrentStack` for example, it uses a `SpinWait` for its job.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty much any of the low-lock concurrent collection class will likely use some combination of `SpinWait` and `Yield`. Though `ConcurrentDictionary` is one notable exception. The list of classes I found include the following.

- ManualResetEventSlim
- SemaphoreSlim
- SpinLock
- Barrier
- ReaderWriterLockSlim
- ConcurrentQueue
- ConcurrentStack
- BlockingCollection

Answer (score 2):

ConcurrentStack and ConcurrentQueue are lock-free collections, however ConcurrentDictionary, ConcurrentBag are using locks. BlockingCollections is just a container so it is not a collection by itself, it has to wrap other threadsafe collections, for example
var bc = new BlockingCollection(new ConcurrentStack());

this is an introductory article about how to use SpinWait in lock-free code
http://www.emadomara.com/2011/08/spinwait-and-lock-free-code.html